# Cactoos Checkstyle Configuration File

Tags: cactoos

I've installed the checkstyle-idea (v8.16) for IntelliJ, there are two options of Configuration files, 'Sun Checks' and 'Google Checks'.

Is there a specific file for Cactoos project? Because both default options are not working when I check all the project, it returns a tone of error style from the source that is already committed at origin/master

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there isn't.

Cactoos uses [qulice](https://github.com/teamed/qulice) for static code analysis in its maven build.

Furthermore, Qulice aggregates several analyzers - not just checkstyle - with custom configuration (and [checks](https://github.com/teamed/qulice/tree/master/qulice-checkstyle/src/main/java/com/qulice/checkstyle) in some cases).

So even if you installed plugins for all the analyzers that qulice aggregates (checkstyle, findbugs, etc), you'd have to somehow import those custom checks as well.

Comment: I see. When I run locally `mvn clean install -Pqulice` it doesn't show me the Checkstyle errors, it builds successfully. I've tried running `mvn clean install --batch-mode -Pqulice`, and now it presents the Checkstyle errors. Thank you for your reply!